# In Angular+Typescript can I inject services and provide parameter in constructor

Tags: angularjs, typescript

If I have a service injection like this:

```
export class MyService {
    private fooService: IFooService;
    public static $inject  = [ "fooService" ];

    constructor(fooService: FooService) {
        this.fooService = fooService;
    }
}
```

But I would like to give fooService a parameter in its constructor, so can I?

Comment: Clarification: What type of value/param are you trying to inject into the service?

Comment: Just a string. I actually changed the architecture so that I don't need to give a parameter in a constructor anymore. Injections are enough.

Comment: Regardless of what you were injecting, the answer from @gilarmran will handle what you need if you run into this scenario again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to calculate something or provide the parameter in the run/config phase use a Provider

```
class MyServiceProvider implements ng.IServiceProvider {
  private customParameter;

  public setCustomParameter(val) {
    this.customParameter = val;
  }

  public $get():Function {
    return () => {
      return new MyService(this.customParameter);
    };
  }
}
```

You now can inject the MyServiceProvider in the config phase and call the setCustomParameter.

If you know what what the parameter is, you can use regular injection and just define an angular variable like this:

```
angular.constant(CONSTANT_NAME, 'CONSTANT_VALUE');
export class fooService {
    public static $inject  = [ "CONSTANT_NAME" ];
    constructor(CONSTANT_NAME) {
    }
}
```